# AJAX commit change to database without submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache

This cat has been skinned several ways in SO, but I can't seem to stretch any in to a way that works for my example.

I have created a table consisting of three columns. The third column is a text box that will display a placeholder of 'Not Installed', or a date. I need an onChange event to trigger a PHP post script to send the entered value to the database.

Independently, the following works:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="./functions/post_Updates.php" method="Post">
         <input name="RAID">
         <input name="InstalledOn">
         <button type="submit" value="go">go </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP

```
$RAID = $_POST['RAID'];
$InstalledOn = $_POST['InstalledOn'];

echo "<p>$RAID</p>";
echo "<p>$InstalledOn</p>";

$tsql = "insert into dbo.test (test) values ('$InstalledOn $RAID')";
```

Upon submit, the TEST table gets updated.

I set up my table elements in the following manner (as part of a PHP function to generate the table itself:
HTML

```
<input type=\"text\" class=\"InstalledOn_Input\" name=\"$r_RAAID\" onChange=\"DynamicUpdateCP($r_RAAID,this.value);\" placeholder=\"$r_CPInstalledOnDate\"></input>
```

JS

```
function DynamicUpdateCP(id,value){
    $.ajax({
        data: {RAID: id, InstalledOn: value},
        url: './functions/post_Updates.php',
        type: 'POST'
    });
    alert(id + ' has changed to ' + value);

}
```

If I remove the $.ajax portion, the alert() fires as expected. Currently, though, editing a field and, either pressing return or changing focus, does nothing at all.

Any guidance on the missing link, here, would be phenomenal. Thank you.

---

@Pointy
I reformatted the portion of the onchange=... to be:

```
onChange=\"DynamicUpdateCP(\"$r_RAAID\",\"this.value\");\"'
```

the error I get, in my debug console, is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

jQuery import statement:

```
<script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you get any error/warning in the developer console of your browser? And is there any activity in the network-tab of the developer tools when you change the content of the input?

Comment: Hah. It's been SO long since I've done dedicated web development (2012) that I forgot to check. I do see 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined..." referring to the $.ajax({ line... not sure what that really means.

Comment: That PHP code looks like it creates the `<input>` element with a "change" callback string that lacks quotes around the ID and value parameters.

Comment: @Wes "$ is not defined" means you forgot to import jQuery.

Comment: Pointy is right, `$.ajax` is part of the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)-library. You have to import that into your document if you want to use it.

Comment: @Pointy Ajax does seem to be imported. Import code added to main body

Comment: @Pointy Also, I updated the input portion. also noted above

Comment: OMG... I got it to work. 1.10.2 may have been too old of a version of JQuery! I added 3.4.1 and it worked INSTANTLY...

Comment: Were you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Barmar as noted above "'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined..." referring to the $.ajax({ line... not sure what that really means."

Comment: That means that jQuery didn't load correctly.

Comment: If you get that error, ALL your jQuery functions should have stopped working, not just `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: was calling the JQuery script using HTTP, not HTTPS. Updated to below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Changed the version of jquery to 3.4.1 and the ajax call worked perfectly.

Comment: There's nothing version-dependent in that AJAX call. It should work fine in 1.10.2.

Comment: I changed my include line from 1.10.2 to 3.4.1 and the exact code worked. Clearly some functional change occurred between versions.

Comment: You were getting an error saying that `$` wasn't defined. The problem wasn't the jQuery version, the problem was that you weren't loading jQuery at all before you changed that. Maybe you had a typo in the URL.

Comment: wow. ok. yeah... that's odd too... I went back to my old include statement and it no longer worked. I then changed from http:// to https:// for the jquery URL and it worked. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You were probably getting a "Mixed content" error in the JavaScript console. If you load the page with HTTPS, you can't load scripts with HTTP.

Comment: That makes sense. I was seeing that, but didn't think it was relevant.